# AWS PHP SDK Filter Aws\Result Object

Tags: php, arrays, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-iam

I am using AWS SDK PHP V3. If i run following code

```
$result = $client->getAccountPasswordPolicy([]);
$result = $result->toArray();
```

It returns result below

```
Array
(
    [PasswordPolicy] => Array
        (
            [MinimumPasswordLength] => 6
            [RequireSymbols] => 
            [RequireNumbers] => 
            [RequireUppercaseCharacters] => 1
            [RequireLowercaseCharacters] => 
            [AllowUsersToChangePassword] => 
            [ExpirePasswords] => 
        )

    [@metadata] => Array
        (
            [statusCode] => 200
            [effectiveUri] => https://iam.amazonaws.com
            [headers] => Array
                (
                    [x-amzn-requestid] => 437f79e9-9ee0-11e7-8a82-47e702eaf8eb
                    [content-type] => text/xml
                    [content-length] => 740
                    [date] => Thu, 21 Sep 2017 15:19:29 GMT
                    [connection] => close
                )

            [transferStats] => Array
                (
                    [http] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

How to get result of only RequireUppercaseCharacters or RequireLowercaseCharacters using AWS SDK or do i have to use array functions to filter data?

[Reference Link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-iam-2010-05-08.html#getaccountpasswordpolicy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ah..you are asking about JMESPath. 
you can achieve what are you are trying to do by

```
$result = $client->getAccountPasswordPolicy([]);
$data = $result->search('PasswordPolicy.RequireUppercaseCharacters');
```

you can read more about [JMESPath here](http://jmespath.org/)

Comment: Yes this will work but how to filter with $result = $client->getAccountPasswordPolicy([]);

Comment: there is no filtering criteria in that method

Comment: Please refer this [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/getting-started/basic-usage.html). It says you can more declaratively extract data from the result.

Comment: ah..you are asking about JMESPath. 
you can achieve what are you are trying to do by 

`$result = $client->getAccountPasswordPolicy([]);

 $data = $result->search('PasswordPolicy.RequireUppercaseCharacters');
`
you can read more about [JMESPath here](http://jmespath.org/)

Answer (score 5):

This seems like it's not possible with the current API. Although it might seem like the method parameter is open to indicate which specific items you need (because it's an array), there is no signal whatsoever of this being the case anywhere in the documentation.

Compare the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_GetAccountPasswordPolicy.html#API_GetAccountPasswordPolicy_Examples) for `getAccountPasswordPolicy()` with, for example, [`ListPolicies()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_ListPolicies.html). The latter explicitly says:

> You can filter the list of policies that is returned using the optional OnlyAttached, Scope, and PathPrefix parameters.

In contrast, the docs for `getAccountPasswordPolicy()` make no mention of this. Not even a mention of the parameter. The parameter *is* mentioned however in the method signature, which makes me think this might come in a future version of the API.

The [CLI documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/get-account-password-policy.html) doesn't have any parameters of the like either, so this definitely seems like something you can't do at the moment.

I did some tests, just in case, with no success:

```
$result = $client->getAccountPasswordPolicy(["RequireUppercaseCharacters"]);
```

returns

> Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Found 1 error while validating the input provided for the GetAccountPasswordPolicy operation:
>    must be an associative array. Found array(2)' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/awss3/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Api/Validator.php:65

And specifying an associative array does not filter anything:

```
$result = $client->getAccountPasswordPolicy(["PasswordPolicy" => ["RequireUppercaseCharacters"]]);

Aws\Result Object
(
    [data:Aws\Result:private] => Array
        (
            [PasswordPolicy] => Array
                (
                    [MinimumPasswordLength] => 6
                    [RequireSymbols] => 
                    [RequireNumbers] => 
                    [RequireUppercaseCharacters] => 1
                    [RequireLowercaseCharacters] => 
                    [AllowUsersToChangePassword] => 1
                    [ExpirePasswords] => 
                    [HardExpiry] => 
                )

            [@metadata] => Array
                (
                    [statusCode] => 200
                    [effectiveUri] => https://iam.amazonaws.com
                    [headers] => Array
                        (
                            // redacted
                        )

                    [transferStats] => Array
                        (
                            [http] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

So, you're only option for now is going through the array's keys, as always:

```
$result["PasswordPolicy"]["RequireUppercaseCharacters"];
```

Comment: In doucumentation it says that "The result object contains a search() method that allows you to more declaratively extract data from the result" but i am not sure how to do this. [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/getting-started/basic-usage.html)

Comment: With CLI you can actually pass parameter to retrieve specific result. In this case following command will return only RequireLowercaseCharacters `aws iam get-account-password-policy --profile default --region ap-south-1 --output json --query 'PasswordPolicy.RequireLowercaseCharacters'`